# How to select every second object?

Tags: macbook-pro

I unfortunately copied few of my photos in the foto application and now I want to delete them. This is the specific setting.

Is there a general way to mark files and select every second object in a short way?

Thank you!

Comment: Select the first file/photo you want to get rid of, then press and hold the command key while clicking on the others you want to get rid of. Then delete the highlighted files/photos It probably not as fast as you like however it's one way to get the job done.

Comment: do you know what folder the images are stored in?

Comment: @VincentRodomista yes. or at least there is no problem moving them to a known folder.

Comment: are you familiar with terminal?

Comment: also, what is the naming convention for repeated photos? Is it along the lines of 

"myPhoto.jpeg"
"myPhoto(1).jpeg"?

Comment: When exported, yes, there is a (1) in brackets. I was not able to find out a clever way to filter them out. Using the terminal should be no problem, though I am not working with it much.

Comment: The question is: how can i restrict the search to a specific data typ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay well if you want a simple way to batch delete duplicates with the naming convention `photo.file`, `photo(1).file` you can do it very easily from the terminal.

First open up your terminal. Then navigate to the folder you are trying to delete stuff from. This is done by using the `cd` command.

For example, if your photos are stored in `your_username/Desktop/my_photo_album` you would type `cd ~/Desktop/my_photo_album`.

From there you can type `ls` to make sure you are in the right folder, and it should list the contents of your folder. After that, all you have to do is type:

`rm *"(1)"*` and it will delete any photo that has `(1)` in the name!